# How can I properly use pip for python?

Tags: python, pip

I am trying to install pip but I don't know why they are not working.

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pygame'

This always appears when I try to do something with the pip

I have already installed my pip by

pip install pygame

I did it multiple times to make sure and this appeared

Requirement already satisfied: pygame in c:\users\myname\appdata\local\programs\python\python39\lib\site-packages (2.0.1)

I even looked at the pip list

```
Package        Version
-------------- -------
beautifulsoup4 4.9.3
numpy          1.21.2
pip            21.2.4
pygame         2.0.1
setuptools     56.0.0
soupsieve      2.2.1
```

there seem to be no problem but I am not able to work with it?
Does anyone know solution to this problem?

I get this when I put import sys; print(sys.version)

3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: This is a common problem. You probably have two versions of python installed on your computer. pip goes to one, python 3.9, and whatever you're using to run your code goes to a different python installation.

Comment: Show us the output of this python code: `import sys; print(sys.version)`

Comment: 3.9.6 (tags/v3.9.6:db3ff76, Jun 28 2021, 15:26:21) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)]

Comment: Well, those are both version 3.9.  Are you running inside a virtual environment?

Comment: Yes, i am using a virtual studio code